# Failing to download a file from a specific URL

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a file using C# (.NET Framework 4.7.2).
The URL in question is
https://manifest.prod.boltdns.net/manifest/v1/hls/v4/aes128/1324209225001/41f5d925-9942-471c-8916-da9d45a92898/10s/master.m3u8?fastly_token=NjQ1ZDYwMGVfNWNhOTM0ODNkZjlmNzM5NWJjYTU5MDA4Mzg0MTlmNzFkYWNmODIxNmQwNzQ3ZjMxNDU0MTJjYTA3YmI4YzM5MQ%3D%3D

The error I get is
"Die zugrunde liegende Verbindung wurde geschlossen: Unerwarteter Fehler beim Senden.."
which translates into
"The underlying connection has been closed: Unexpected error while sending.."

The file downloads fine in Mozilla Firefox, but I cannot get it to download in my program.

I'm using this code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)12288
                                                   | (SecurityProtocolType)3072
                                                   | (SecurityProtocolType)768
                                                   | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://manifest.prod.boltdns.net/manifest/v1/hls/v4/aes128/1324209225001/41f5d925-9942-471c-8916-da9d45a92898/10s/master.m3u8?fastly_token=NjQ1ZDYwMGVfNWNhOTM0ODNkZjlmNzM5NWJjYTU5MDA4Mzg0MTlmNzFkYWNmODIxNmQwNzQ3ZjMxNDU0MTJjYTA3YmI4YzM5MQ%3D%3D").Result;
                File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.m3u8", response);
            }
```

NB: the .Result is just there so I could write a bare minimum console application without having to deal with async code here.
I've also tried using WebClient():

```
var wc = new WebClient();
var bytes = wc.DownloadData("https://manifest.prod.boltdns.net/manifest/v1/hls/v4/aes128/1324209225001/41f5d925-9942-471c-8916-da9d45a92898/10s/master.m3u8?fastly_token=NjQ1ZDYwMGVfNWNhOTM0ODNkZjlmNzM5NWJjYTU5MDA4Mzg0MTlmNzFkYWNmODIxNmQwNzQ3ZjMxNDU0MTJjYTA3YmI4YzM5MQ%3D%3D");
File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.m3u8", response);
```

I would like to be able to download the file programmatically.
NB: the URL provided above will only be valid until 05/13/2023, the token will expire.

Comment: Both methods work fine for me. Voting to close as it isn't possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried this on a different machine or network? It sounds like potentially a firewall is blocking the connection

Comment: If it works in a browser but not with an `HttpClient`, maybe the server is expecting some kind of `User-Agent` header and closing the connection if it isn't there.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It isn't, unless some proxy server is in the way that does expect that.

Comment: I had already suspected my firewall and had disabled it completely - unfortunately the error persists.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel
I've added
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0");
No change in behaviour.

Comment: @esp Of course there isn't, because the code you have already works. There's something outside of the code that's the issue.

Comment: I've tried it now on a different machine - same error.
Another URL works just fine:
var bytes = wc.DownloadData("https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_fmp4/master.m3u8");

Comment: Again: the code you have already works. There's something outside of the code that's the issue.

Comment: Here's a demonstration of both of your download codes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7DmsIjK1kY

Comment: I had a thought: I don't have IPv6 enabled. The DNS records make IPv6 addresses available for the `manifest.prod.boltdns.net` domain. Could it be an issue when IPv6 is used? You could confirm this by disabling IPv6 on your machine.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama
Thanks for the commitment with the youtube video, I really appreciate it!
I've disabled IPV6 on my network adapter, the error persists.
The odd thing is, this all worked until yesterday (on another URL, but also on boltdns.net) and all the days before, since I started this project (it's about letting me save certain playlists, that become unavailable after a few days).

Comment: It's a really odd one. All I can think is that perhaps it's some kind of deliberate action by the server, but you'd think you would see that in Firefox too. ‍♂️